# ¿como guardar al usuario logueado mediante request.user?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Necesito que el usuario logueado sea igual a mi votante porque con el código que tengo se me actualizan todas la votación guardadas cada vez que guardo una nueva

Este es mi modelo:

```
class Votante(models.Model):
    vo=models.Manager()
    usuario=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null='True')
    ide=models.IntegerField(unique='True',primary_key='TRUE')
    tfno=models.CharField(max_length=20,)
    grado=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    curso=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    fecha_votacion=models.DateTimeField(auto_now='TRUE')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.usuario.username

    #/def crear_usuario(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    #if created:
        #Votante.objects.create(usuario=instance)

def guardar_usuario(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    instance.Votante.save()

class Candidato(models.Model):
    c=models.Manager()
    informacion=models.ForeignKey(Votante,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null='False')
    idvotacion=models.IntegerField(unique='TRUE',primary_key='TRUE',verbose_name="Número_de_Tarjeton")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.informacion.usuario.username

class Votacion(models.Model):
    v=models.Manager()
    votante=models.OneToOneField(Votante,null='False',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    candidato=models.ForeignKey(Candidato,null='False',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha=models.DateField(auto_now='TRUE')
    hora=models.TimeField(auto_now='True')
    n_votos=models.IntegerField(null='true',blank='true',default=1)
```

Este es el cojunto de mis vistas:

```
@login_required
def votacion(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = VotacionForm()
        contexto={
            'form':form
        }
    else:
        form = VotacionForm(request.POST)
        contexto={
            'form':form
        }
        if form.is_valid():
            voto=Votacion.votantes = request.user
            voto.save()
            form.save()
            return redirect('logout') 

    return render(request, "votacion.html",contexto)
```

Segundo: Mostrar solo el numero de votos por candidato y no toda la lista general

Answer (score 1):

Bueno leyendo tu problema pues te daré unas recomendaciones.

Lo primero es que no deberías de crear una clase Votante si va a ser el mismo usuario logueado en la aplicación. Los campos adicionales como el teléfono, grado, curso, fecha_de_votacion deberían ir en el modelo de Usuario que ya debes de tener.

Como consejo siempre coloca los atributos de la manera más explicita por ejemplo, en vez de colocar tfno coloca telefono.

Una vez realizado esos cambios crea tu formulario de votación con los campos que mencionas y de esa manera cuando veas tu formulario en la pagina veras que tanto el votante como el candidato serán listas desplegables y ahí te saldrán las opciones.

En la vista lo unico que tendrás será algo como esto:

```
def RegistrarVotacion(request):
    form = VotacionForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = VotacionForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          votacion = form.save(commit=False)
          votacion.votante= request.user
          votacion.save()
          return redirect('logout')
    else:
         form = VotacionForm()

    return render(request, "votacion.html",{
     'form':form
     })
```

Nota: no es necesario que tu coloques los ids de las clases ya que por defecto django te las genera, tampoco es necesario colocar null='true' puede colocarlo null=True

Espero que te ayude y cualquier cosa no dudes en comentar!

Comment: De antemano gracias, ya eh hecho todas las correcciones sugeridas pero eh formulado mal las preguntas y pido disculpas. Lo que necesito como tal es que en el momento de guardar mi votante sea igual al votante que está definido en el modelo votación ésto para que el votante no pueda votar más, al momento de hacer el formulario me muestra una lista de todos los votantes(usuarios) y yo puedo seleccionarlo cosa que no me sirve ya que yo puedo escoger a otro usuario distinto, lo que quiero es guardar al usuario logueado como el que realizó la votación sin utilizar el formulario.

Comment: Eso lo realizaba con el código que mostré pero pasaba que ese código me actualizaba todos los registros de la base de datos y me guardaba ese votante en todos cosa que es una mala práctica. Por eso quiero hacerlo con el request.user

Comment: Vale con todo gusto, edite la respuesta con lo que pienso soluciona tu pregunta, me cuentas cualquier cosa

Comment: Eh intentado hacer lo que me dijiste pero me reporta el siguiente error: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: admin>>": "Votacion.votante" must be a"Votante" instance

Comment: Claro, lo que pasa es que en tu modelo tienes en la clase Votación a votante como un campo uno a uno con Votante y por ese motivo te genera ese error. Si tu ya no tienes el modelo de Votante y utilizas el de usuario tienes que colocarlo como una relación con Usuario y ahí si funcionaría

Comment: Aun tengo la clase de votante porqué pensé que no habías entendido la pregunta ya que estaba mal formulada pero cambiaré la clase por la de usuario.